# Error with LangChain ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages

Tags: python, langchain

As shown in [LangChain Quickstart](https://python.langchain.com/docs/get_started/quickstart), I am trying the following Python code:

```
from langchain.prompts.chat import ChatPromptTemplate
template = "You are a helpful assistant that translates {input_language} to {output_language}."
human_template = "{text}"

chat_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages([
    ("system", template),
    ("human", human_template),
])

chat_prompt.format_messages(input_language="English", output_language="French", text="I love programming.")
```

But when I run the above code, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/yser364/Projets/SinappsIrdOpenaiQA/promptWorkout.py", line 6, in <module>
     chat_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages([
   File "/home/yser364/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/prompts/chat.py", line 220, in from_messages
     return cls(input_variables=list(input_vars), messages=messages)
   File "/home/yser364/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/load/serializable.py", line 64, in __init__
     super().__init__(**kwargs)
   File "pydantic/main.py", line 341, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__
 pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 4 validation errors for ChatPromptTemplate
 messages -> 0
   value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)
 messages -> 0
   value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)
 messages -> 1
   value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)
 messages -> 1
   value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)
```

I use Python 3.10.12.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your example is from the [Prompt templates section](https://python.langchain.com/docs/get_started/quickstart#prompt-templates) of the LangChain Quickstart tutorial. I did not spot any differences, so it should work as given.

I tried out the example myself, with an additional loop to output the messages created by `chat_prompt.format_messages`:

```
from langchain.prompts.chat import ChatPromptTemplate
template = "You are a helpful assistant that translates {input_language} to {output_language}."
human_template = "{text}"

chat_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages([
    ("system", template),
    ("human", human_template),
])

messages = chat_prompt.format_messages(input_language="English", output_language="French", text="I love programming.")
for message in messages:
    print(message.__repr__())
```

The example works without any errors. The result is very similar to what is shown in the tutorial, although not identical:

```
SystemMessage(content='You are a helpful assistant that translates English to French.', additional_kwargs={})
HumanMessage(content='I love programming.', additional_kwargs={}, example=False)
```

I ran the test with Python 3.9.5 and LangChain 0.0.300, which is the [lastest version](https://pypi.org/project/langchain/) on PyPI. According to PyPI, it supports Python >=3.8.1 and <4.0.

Maybe your version of LangChain or one of its dependencies is outdated? Try to run it in a new [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) with a fresh install of LangChain.

Comment: I upgraded and it worked ....easy thx
sorry I am new to Python

Comment: im using python 3.11 and langchain 0.0.181 and it still gives an error:/

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'm using python 3.11 and langchain 0.0.181 and it still gives an error. I changed the code from the below:

```
final_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages([
         ("system", "You are an enthusiast supportive and talkative virtual assistant that answer user questions precisely."),
         ("user", "{relevant_data} \n Based on my measurement, I want you to think step-by-step and answer my question precisely:\n{question}?")])
```

to this

```
messages = [
    SystemMessagePromptTemplate.from_template("Text"),
    HumanMessagePromptTemplate.from_template("Text")
]

final_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(messages)
```

Hope it saved someone's time.

Comment: Do you have the chance to update your installed version of LangChain? 0.0.181 is quite old and uses an outdated API. The current version is 0.1.8, for which you do not need to change the tutorial's source code.